# Web scraping: Scraping articles from Hindi online newspapers

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie when it comes to scraping libraries and I have started with BeautifulSoup for scraping. Below is a HTML snippet from a URL of the 'Dainik Jaagran' (Hindi newspaper) :

```
<div class="article-summery">अमित शाह ने दिल्ली गेट चौराहे पर नुक्कड़ सभा में कानून व्यवस्था के बहाने सपा पर चौतरफा हमला बोला।</div><p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>मेरठ (जेएनएन)। </strong>पीएम नरेंद्र मोदी की रैली से एक दिन पहले मेरठ में पदयात्रा करने पहुंचे राष्ट्रीय अध्यक्ष अमित शाह ने कांग्रेस-सपा गठबंधन पर निशाना साधते हुए राहुल-अखिलेश की जुगलबंदी को सूबे के लिए छल बताया। कहा कि दोनों अवसरवादी शहजादे प्रदेश को बर्बाद कर देंगे। पश्चिम में बेंच के मसले पर कोई ठोस आश्र्वासन उन्होंने नहीं दिया।</p><p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">शुक्रवार को मेरठ शहर में पैदल मार्च करने पहुंचे अमित शाह ने दिल्ली गेट चौराहे पर नुक्कड़ सभा में कानून व्यवस्था के बहाने सपा पर चौतरफा हमला बोला। कहा कि गुरुवार को ब्रह्मपुरी में व्यापारी अभिषेक की सरेआम गोली मारकर हत्या कर दी गई, पुलिस मूक बनी रही। अखिलेश और राहुल को जवाब देना होगा। सूबे में रोजाना 24 महिलाओं से दुष्कर्म, 21 दुष्कर्म की कोशिश एवं 13 हत्याएं होती हैं। दुष्कर्म की वारदातों में 161 फीसद का इजाफा हुआ है। 70 फीसद घटनाएं तो मंत्रियों के इलाकों में हुई हैं। साफ है कि अपराधियों को राजनीतिक संरक्षण है।</p><p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">अमित शाह ने राहुल गांधी और अखिलेश पर तंज कसते हुए कहा कि एक ने केंद्र को, जबकि दूसरे ने सूबे को लूटा। वेस्ट यूपी की नब्ज को टटोलते हुए अमित शाह ने कहा कि भाजपा सत्ता में आई तो यांत्रिक कत्लखानों पर पाबंदी लगेगी। छेड़छाड़ की घटनाओं पर कहा कि एंटी रोमियो सेल बनेगा। गन्ना किसानों को 120 दिन के भीतर भुगतान मिलेगा। हालांकि संबोधन के दौरान वह मेरठ के स्थान पर लखनऊ भी बोल गए। पदयात्रा निरस्त कर किया रोडशोनिर्धारित समय दस बजे से करीब दो घंटे देर से दिल्ली गेट चौराहा पहुंचे अमित शाह का भाजपाइयों ने जोरदार स्वागत किया। गुरुवार को ब्रह्मापुरी मोहल्ले में व्यपारी की हत्या पर संवेदना जताते हुए उन्होंने पदयात्रा निरस्त कर दी। बाद में उनका रोडशो हुआ।</p><p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">याद दिलाई सर्जिकल स्ट्राइक</p><p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">खुर्जा के पॉलीटेक्निक मैदान में शुक्रवार शाम जनसभा में भी अमित शाह ने कांग्रेस-सपा गठजोड़ पर निशाना साधा। कैराना के पलायन पर सवाल उठाए। कहा कि अगर यूपी में सरकार बनी तो किसी भी स्थान से होने वाले पलायन के लिए वहां के डीएम को जिम्मेदार माना जाएगा। पाकिस्तान की गोली के बदले हम गोला दाग रहे, कहते हुए उन्होंने सर्जिकल स्ट्राइक की भी याद दिलाई।</p><p>
<p>
```

Below is the Python script to extract the same :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.jagran.com/elections/uttar-pradesh-amit-shah-foot-march-turned-into-road-show-on-car-in-meerut-15471512.html?src=p1"
web_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'html.parser')
extract_div = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "article-summery"})
paragraph = soup.findAll("p", {"style" : "text-align: justify;"})

print (extract_div)
print (paragraph)
```

Below is the output for the Python script :

```
[<div class="article-summery">\u0905\u092e\u093f\u0924 \u0936\u093e\u0939 \u0928\u0947 \u0926\u093f\u0932\u094d\u0932\u0940 \u0917\u0947\u091f \u091a\u094c\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0947 \u092a\u0930 \u0928\u0941\u0915\u094d\u0915\u0921\u093c \u0938\u092d\u093e \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0915\u093e\u0928\u0942\u0928 \u0935\u094d\u092f\u0935\u0938\u094d\u0925\u093e \u0915\u0947 \u092c\u0939\u093e\u0928\u0947 \u0938\u092a\u093e \u092a\u0930 \u091a\u094c\u0924\u0930\u092b\u093e \u0939\u092e\u0932\u093e \u092c\u094b\u0932\u093e\u0964</div>]
[<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>\u092e\u0947\u0930\u0920 (\u091c\u0947\u090f\u0928\u090f\u0928)\u0964 </strong>\u092a\u0940\u090f\u092e \u0928\u0930\u0947\u0902\u0926\u094d\u0930 \u092e\u094b\u0926\u0940 \u0915\u0940 \u0930\u0948\u0932\u0940 \u0938\u0947 \u090f\u0915 \u0926\u093f\u0928 \u092a\u0939\u0932\u0947 \u092e\u0947\u0930\u0920 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u092a\u0926\u092f\u093e\u0924\u094d\u0930\u093e \u0915\u0930\u0928\u0947 \u092a\u0939\u0941\u0902\u091a\u0947 \u0930\u093e\u0937\u094d\u091f\u094d\u0930\u0940\u092f \u0905\u0927\u094d\u092f\u0915\u094d\u0937 \u0905\u092e\u093f\u0924 \u0936\u093e\u0939 \u0928\u0947 \u0915\u093e\u0902\u0917\u094d\u0930\u0947\u0938-\u0938\u092a\u093e \u0917\u0920\u092c\u0902\u0927\u0928 \u092a\u0930 \u0928\u093f\u0936\u093e\u0928\u093e \u0938\u093e\u0927\u0924\u0947 \u0939\u0941\u090f \u0930\u093e\u0939\u0941\u0932-\u0905\u0916\u093f\u0932\u0947\u0936 \u0915\u0940 \u091c\u0941\u0917\u0932\u092c\u0902\u0926\u0940 \u0915\u094b \u0938\u0942\u092c\u0947 \u0915\u0947 \u0932\u093f\u090f \u091b\u0932 \u092c\u0924\u093e\u092f\u093e\u0964 \u0915\u0939\u093e \u0915\u093f \u0926\u094b\u0928\u094b\u0902 \u0905\u0935\u0938\u0930\u0935\u093e\u0926\u0940 \u0936\u0939\u091c\u093e\u0926\u0947 \u092a\u094d\u0930\u0926\u0947\u0936 \u0915\u094b \u092c\u0930\u094d\u092c\u093e\u0926 \u0915\u0930 \u0926\u0947\u0902\u0917\u0947\u0964 \u092a\u0936\u094d\u091a\u093f\u092e \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u092c\u0947\u0902\u091a \u0915\u0947 \u092e\u0938\u0932\u0947 \u092a\u0930 \u0915\u094b\u0908 \u0920\u094b\u0938 \u0906\u0936\u094d\u0930\u094d\u0935\u093e\u0938\u0928 \u0909\u0928\u094d\u0939\u094b\u0902\u0928\u0947 \u0928\u0939\u0940\u0902 \u0926\u093f\u092f\u093e\u0964</p>, <p style="text-align: justify;">\u0936\u0941\u0915\u094d\u0930\u0935\u093e\u0930 \u0915\u094b \u092e\u0947\u0930\u0920 \u0936\u0939\u0930 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u092a\u0948\u0926\u0932 \u092e\u093e\u0930\u094d\u091a \u0915\u0930\u0928\u0947 \u092a\u0939\u0941\u0902\u091a\u0947 \u0905\u092e\u093f\u0924 \u0936\u093e\u0939 \u0928\u0947 \u0926\u093f\u0932\u094d\u0932\u0940 \u0917\u0947\u091f \u091a\u094c\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0947 \u092a\u0930 \u0928\u0941\u0915\u094d\u0915\u0921\u093c \u0938\u092d\u093e \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0915\u093e\u0928\u0942\u0928 \u0935\u094d\u092f\u0935\u0938\u094d\u0925\u093e \u0915\u0947 \u092c\u0939\u093e\u0928\u0947 \u0938\u092a\u093e \u092a\u0930 \u091a\u094c\u0924\u0930\u092b\u093e \u0939\u092e\u0932\u093e \u092c\u094b\u0932\u093e\u0964 \u0915\u0939\u093e \u0915\u093f \u0917\u0941\u0930\u0941\u0935\u093e\u0930 \u0915\u094b \u092c\u094d\u0930\u0939\u094d\u092e\u092a\u0941\u0930\u0940 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0935\u094d\u092f\u093e\u092a\u093e\u0930\u0940 \u0905\u092d\u093f\u0937\u0947\u0915 \u0915\u0940 \u0938\u0930\u0947\u0906\u092e \u0917\u094b\u0932\u0940 \u092e\u093e\u0930\u0915\u0930 \u0939\u0924\u094d\u092f\u093e \u0915\u0930 \u0926\u0940 \u0917\u0908, \u092a\u0941\u0932\u093f\u0938 \u092e\u0942\u0915 \u092c\u0928\u0940 \u0930\u0939\u0940\u0964 \u0905\u0916\u093f\u0932\u0947\u0936 \u0914\u0930 \u0930\u093e\u0939\u0941\u0932 \u0915\u094b \u091c\u0935\u093e\u092c \u0926\u0947\u0928\u093e \u0939\u094b\u0917\u093e\u0964 \u0938\u0942\u092c\u0947 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0930\u094b\u091c\u093e\u0928\u093e 24 \u092e\u0939\u093f\u0932\u093e\u0913\u0902 \u0938\u0947 \u0926\u0941\u0937\u094d\u0915\u0930\u094d\u092e, 21 \u0926\u0941\u0937\u094d\u0915\u0930\u094d\u092e \u0915\u0940 \u0915\u094b\u0936\u093f\u0936 \u090f\u0935\u0902 13 \u0939\u0924\u094d\u092f\u093e\u090f\u0902 \u0939\u094b\u0924\u0940 \u0939\u0948\u0902\u0964 \u0926\u0941\u0937\u094d\u0915\u0930\u094d\u092e \u0915\u0940 \u0935\u093e\u0930\u0926\u093e\u0924\u094b\u0902 \u092e\u0947\u0902 161 \u092b\u0940\u0938\u0926 \u0915\u093e \u0907\u091c\u093e\u092b\u093e \u0939\u0941\u0906 \u0939\u0948\u0964 70 \u092b\u0940\u0938\u0926 \u0918\u091f\u0928\u093e\u090f\u0902 \u0924\u094b \u092e\u0902\u0924\u094d\u0930\u093f\u092f\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u0947 \u0907\u0932\u093e\u0915\u094b\u0902 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0939\u0941\u0908 \u0939\u0948\u0902\u0964 \u0938\u093e\u092b \u0939\u0948 \u0915\u093f \u0905\u092a\u0930\u093e\u0927\u093f\u092f\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u094b \u0930\u093e\u091c\u0928\u0940\u0924\u093f\u0915 \u0938\u0902\u0930\u0915\u094d\u0937\u0923 \u0939\u0948\u0964</p>, <p style="text-align: justify;">\u0905\u092e\u093f\u0924 \u0936\u093e\u0939 \u0928\u0947 \u0930\u093e\u0939\u0941\u0932 \u0917\u093e\u0902\u0927\u0940 \u0914\u0930 \u0905\u0916\u093f\u0932\u0947\u0936 \u092a\u0930 \u0924\u0902\u091c \u0915\u0938\u0924\u0947 \u0939\u0941\u090f \u0915\u0939\u093e \u0915\u093f \u090f\u0915 \u0928\u0947 \u0915\u0947\u0902\u0926\u094d\u0930 \u0915\u094b, \u091c\u092c\u0915\u093f \u0926\u0942\u0938\u0930\u0947 \u0928\u0947 \u0938\u0942\u092c\u0947 \u0915\u094b \u0932\u0942\u091f\u093e\u0964 \u0935\u0947\u0938\u094d\u091f \u092f\u0942\u092a\u0940 \u0915\u0940 \u0928\u092c\u094d\u091c \u0915\u094b \u091f\u091f\u094b\u0932\u0924\u0947 \u0939\u0941\u090f \u0905\u092e\u093f\u0924 \u0936\u093e\u0939 \u0928\u0947 \u0915\u0939\u093e \u0915\u093f \u092d\u093e\u091c\u092a\u093e \u0938\u0924\u094d\u0924\u093e \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0906\u0908 \u0924\u094b \u092f\u093e\u0902\u0924\u094d\u0930\u093f\u0915 \u0915\u0924\u094d\u0932\u0916\u093e\u0928\u094b\u0902 \u092a\u0930 \u092a\u093e\u092c\u0902\u0926\u0940 \u0932\u0917\u0947\u0917\u0940\u0964 \u091b\u0947\u0921\u093c\u091b\u093e\u0921\u093c \u0915\u0940 \u0918\u091f\u0928\u093e\u0913\u0902 \u092a\u0930 \u0915\u0939\u093e \u0915\u093f \u090f\u0902\u091f\u0940 \u0930\u094b\u092e\u093f\u092f\u094b \u0938\u0947\u0932 \u092c\u0928\u0947\u0917\u093e\u0964 \u0917\u0928\u094d\u0928\u093e \u0915\u093f\u0938\u093e\u0928\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u094b 120 \u0926\u093f\u0928 \u0915\u0947 \u092d\u0940\u0924\u0930 \u092d\u0941\u0917\u0924\u093e\u0928 \u092e\u093f\u0932\u0947\u0917\u093e\u0964 \u0939\u093e\u0932\u093e\u0902\u0915\u093f \u0938\u0902\u092c\u094b\u0927\u0928 \u0915\u0947 \u0926\u094c\u0930\u093e\u0928 \u0935\u0939 \u092e\u0947\u0930\u0920 \u0915\u0947 \u0938\u094d\u0925\u093e\u0928 \u092a\u0930 \u0932\u0916\u0928\u090a \u092d\u0940 \u092c\u094b\u0932 \u0917\u090f\u0964 \u092a\u0926\u092f\u093e\u0924\u094d\u0930\u093e \u0928\u093f\u0930\u0938\u094d\u0924 \u0915\u0930 \u0915\u093f\u092f\u093e \u0930\u094b\u0921\u0936\u094b\u0928\u093f\u0930\u094d\u0927\u093e\u0930\u093f\u0924 \u0938\u092e\u092f \u0926\u0938 \u092c\u091c\u0947 \u0938\u0947 \u0915\u0930\u0940\u092c \u0926\u094b \u0918\u0902\u091f\u0947 \u0926\u0947\u0930 \u0938\u0947 \u0926\u093f\u0932\u094d\u0932\u0940 \u0917\u0947\u091f \u091a\u094c\u0930\u093e\u0939\u093e \u092a\u0939\u0941\u0902\u091a\u0947 \u0905\u092e\u093f\u0924 \u0936\u093e\u0939 \u0915\u093e \u092d\u093e\u091c\u092a\u093e\u0907\u092f\u094b\u0902 \u0928\u0947 \u091c\u094b\u0930\u0926\u093e\u0930 \u0938\u094d\u0935\u093e\u0917\u0924 \u0915\u093f\u092f\u093e\u0964 \u0917\u0941\u0930\u0941\u0935\u093e\u0930 \u0915\u094b \u092c\u094d\u0930\u0939\u094d\u092e\u093e\u092a\u0941\u0930\u0940 \u092e\u094b\u0939\u0932\u094d\u0932\u0947 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0935\u094d\u092f\u092a\u093e\u0930\u0940 \u0915\u0940 \u0939\u0924\u094d\u092f\u093e \u092a\u0930 \u0938\u0902\u0935\u0947\u0926\u0928\u093e \u091c\u0924\u093e\u0924\u0947 \u0939\u0941\u090f \u0909\u0928\u094d\u0939\u094b\u0902\u0928\u0947 \u092a\u0926\u092f\u093e\u0924\u094d\u0930\u093e \u0928\u093f\u0930\u0938\u094d\u0924 \u0915\u0930 \u0926\u0940\u0964 \u092c\u093e\u0926 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0909\u0928\u0915\u093e \u0930\u094b\u0921\u0936\u094b \u0939\u0941\u0906\u0964</p>, <p style="text-align: justify;">\u092f\u093e\u0926 \u0926\u093f\u0932\u093e\u0908 \u0938\u0930\u094d\u091c\u093f\u0915\u0932 \u0938\u094d\u091f\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0907\u0915</p>, <p style="text-align: justify;">\u0916\u0941\u0930\u094d\u091c\u093e \u0915\u0947 \u092a\u0949\u0932\u0940\u091f\u0947\u0915\u094d\u0928\u093f\u0915 \u092e\u0948\u0926\u093e\u0928 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0936\u0941\u0915\u094d\u0930\u0935\u093e\u0930 \u0936\u093e\u092e \u091c\u0928\u0938\u092d\u093e \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u092d\u0940 \u0905\u092e\u093f\u0924 \u0936\u093e\u0939 \u0928\u0947 \u0915\u093e\u0902\u0917\u094d\u0930\u0947\u0938-\u0938\u092a\u093e \u0917\u0920\u091c\u094b\u0921\u093c \u092a\u0930 \u0928\u093f\u0936\u093e\u0928\u093e \u0938\u093e\u0927\u093e\u0964 \u0915\u0948\u0930\u093e\u0928\u093e \u0915\u0947 \u092a\u0932\u093e\u092f\u0928 \u092a\u0930 \u0938\u0935\u093e\u0932 \u0909\u0920\u093e\u090f\u0964 \u0915\u0939\u093e \u0915\u093f \u0905\u0917\u0930 \u092f\u0942\u092a\u0940 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0938\u0930\u0915\u093e\u0930 \u092c\u0928\u0940 \u0924\u094b \u0915\u093f\u0938\u0940 \u092d\u0940 \u0938\u094d\u0925\u093e\u0928 \u0938\u0947 \u0939\u094b\u0928\u0947 \u0935\u093e\u0932\u0947 \u092a\u0932\u093e\u092f\u0928 \u0915\u0947 \u0932\u093f\u090f \u0935\u0939\u093e\u0902 \u0915\u0947 \u0921\u0940\u090f\u092e \u0915\u094b \u091c\u093f\u092e\u094d\u092e\u0947\u0926\u093e\u0930 \u092e\u093e\u0928\u093e \u091c\u093e\u090f\u0917\u093e\u0964 \u092a\u093e\u0915\u093f\u0938\u094d\u0924\u093e\u0928 \u0915\u0940 \u0917\u094b\u0932\u0940 \u0915\u0947 \u092c\u0926\u0932\u0947 \u0939\u092e \u0917\u094b\u0932\u093e \u0926\u093e\u0917 \u0930\u0939\u0947, \u0915\u0939\u0924\u0947 \u0939\u0941\u090f \u0909\u0928\u094d\u0939\u094b\u0902\u0928\u0947 \u0938\u0930\u094d\u091c\u093f\u0915\u0932 \u0938\u094d\u091f\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0907\u0915 \u0915\u0940 \u092d\u0940 \u092f\u093e\u0926 \u0926\u093f\u0932\u093e\u0908\u0964</p>, <p style="text-align: justify;"> </p>, <p style="text-align: justify;"><a href="http://www.jagran.com/elections/uttar-pradesh-varun-gandhi-the-star-campaigner-for-bjp-in-the-third-and-fourth-phases-of-up-election-15464279.html?src=up-state">\u092f\u0939 \u092d\u0940 \u092a\u0922\u093c\u0947\u0902:</a> <a href="http://www.jagran.com/elections/uttar-pradesh-akhilesh-yadav-said-bjp-is-out-of-contest-in-up-assembly-election-15466449.html?src=Search-ART-akhilesh-yadav">Election 2017: \u0905\u0916\u093f\u0932\u0947\u0936 \u092f\u093e\u0926\u0935 \u0928\u0947 \u0915\u0939\u093e- \u092d\u093e\u091c\u092a\u093e \u0905\u092c \u092f\u0942\u092a\u0940 \u0915\u0947 \u091a\u0941\u0928\u093e\u0935 \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u0932\u0921\u093c\u093e\u0908 \u0938\u0947 \u092c\u093e\u0939\u0930</a></p>]
```

I would like to display the result in Hindi text, suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well there is no attribute such as text which results in an AttributeError @AlexDotis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When i running your code, i have the same result as with you!

Try this :

For Python 3:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.jagran.com/elections/uttar-pradesh-amit-shah-foot-march-turned-into-road-show-on-car-in-meerut-15471512.html?src=p1"
web_page = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'html.parser')

for extract_div in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "article-summery"}):
        print (extract_div.text)

for paragraph in soup.findAll("p", {"style" : "text-align: justify;"}):
        print (paragraph.text)
```

For Python 2 :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.jagran.com/elections/uttar-pradesh-amit-shah-foot-march-turned-into-road-show-on-car-in-meerut-15471512.html?src=p1"
web_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'html.parser')
for extract_div in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "article-summery"}):
    print extract_div.text

for paragraph in soup.findAll("p", {"style" : "text-align: justify;"}):
    print paragraph.text
```

It works for me !

I hope this helps you!

Comment: It was throwing a UnicodeEncode error, so I changed it to print input extract_div.text.encode('utf-8')  and paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') respectively. I suppose I need to be thorough with reading documentation. Thanks a ton for the help@AlexDotis

Comment: Very nice !! I'm glad i helped you !